# SendEmail script Google spreadsheets - multiple options

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I'm trying to send out an email from google spreadsheets with multiple options:

if I type first attachments and then htlmBody in the code, like below, the email goes out with the correct body content and structure but the two attachments don't appear

```
MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject,{attachments:[blob,blob1]} ,{htmlBody:html});
```

While if I type first htmlBody and then attachments in the code, like below, the email goes out with the body "[object Object]" but the two attachments are present!

```
MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject ,{htmlBody:html},{attachments:[blob,blob1]});
```

What am I doing wrong? Why I can't use both? And in the case i would need to add a "cc" option?

I already tried with only one attachment and the result is the same!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)

```
GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject , 'body if no html', {
     htmlBody:html, attachments: [blob,blob1]
 });
```

if you know they have HTML you can replace the no HTML body text with an empty string but the placeholder and empty string must be there.

```
GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject , '', {
         htmlBody:html, attachments: [blob,blob1]
     });
```

Comment: Thank you Michael! You solved my problem and really made my day!